# Mohaj al Da'awat in other languages

Tags: shiism, books

Salaam,

Does anyone knows if this book((Mohaj al Da'awat) is available in any other language other than farsi. Then please do send the link of the book.

Comment: As the title is Arabic it is available in Arabic too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pilgrimage in other languages
Muhaj al-Da`wat and Minhaj al-Ibadat, A book in Arabic on prayer and ablution, written by Sayyid Ibn Tawus (died 664 AH). In this book, he started quoting supplications and amulets from the Holy Prophet (PBUH) and ended them with the Imam of the Age (AS), and after that, he also quoted cases from non-Imams. Mahj al-Dawat has always been considered and trusted by Shiite scholars.

Ref: https://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D9%85%D9%87%D8%AC_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D8%B9%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AA_%D9%88_%D9%85%D9%86%D9%87%D8%AC_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AA_(%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8)